# 12V MUX with single output

Tags: components

I have a VBus of 12VDC. I would like to take 14 discrete inputs and Light a single LED for each input that is active.

I was planning on just doing a simple current limiting resistor and having a common anode and allowing the inputs to switch ground.

A new requirement was added: If any of the inputs are active they want to switch on a 500mA load on. (ie a buzzer or light). I would most likely do this with a NFET.

I would like to try and do this as cheaply as possible.

If i use a micro then I need to generate 5v. I could probably do a micro / powersupply / and either optos or resistor divider for the inputs this would cost around $8.00 per board.

Can anyone suggest any easier / cheaper way to mux the LED inputs together?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're still using each of the signals to drive the LEDs and need to combine them to turn on a single buzzer or light. You can do this with buffers (or inverters for active low signals, not shown). Simply pass each signal through a buffer and combine the outputs to drive the single load device. A discrete component view might look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDYIWA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use three CD4050Bs (HEX buffers). This will provide easy expansion for up to 18 inputs (I would put them all on the PCB and, for now, only populate the 14 that will be needed). If your signals are active low, use three CD4049UBs (HEX inverters) instead and hook up the LEDs as you've drawn them in your schematic.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try this! I will also make sure that I state my questions more clearly.

Comment: The 7404 or 7407 still requires a max vcc of 7vdc is there any parts out there that would be able to take in the 12v bus w/ out modification? I could use a voltage divider for that or a 7805

Comment: Oh, my mistake. There are certainly such parts. No need to invoke a regulator for this solution. Just use something like a CD4050B instead. Edited answer.

Comment: @Samuel 14 inputs - only 2 hex buffers, what happened to the last two inputs? 7407s only work up to 7V and  are open collectors - you need a pull up resistor for each. This circuit will not work. Substitute CMOS 4000 series logic e.g. 4049 hex inverter.

Comment: @JImDearden Yes. Read the two comments above yours.

Comment: @Samuel Read them just **after I posted**. It was simply a head's up to get you to edit your answer and get it sorted before folk on here start mark it down. Once the answer has the green tick you can't delete.

Comment: I think you can use diodes instead of buffers here. Connect the anode where you have shown the buffer inputs and connect all of the cathodes to the NMOS gate.

Comment: @JImDearden Appreciated, honestly. I was just addressing your comment. I'm sure we were editing/composing in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (a bit difficulty understanding) that you want 14 LEDs, one for each input? You could use something like this:

http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn72/fn7288.pdf

Just use 4 of them, they're cheap and reliable. Mouser has some that run 6 drivers off of 12V, but I would go with the 7457 as I have had a lot of success with it.

edit: Because you want one for one, you really don't need a MUX.

Comment: I am sorry if i was not clear enough. For each input there is a corresponding LED that should be turned on. Then there is one single output that should be asserted if _ANY_ of the LEDs are asserted. That is what I was looking for the mux for.

Comment: Are they TTL level signals (Or just that 12V bus?) If just TTL, you could just break them off before the quad drivers (or whatever driver you choose), put them into a 14 input OR gate array, then buffer the output through one of the two extra driver gates you would have (if you used my drivers)

edit: The others suggesting that a pullup would work are correct. I'm was actually just assuming that your signal bus didn't want to supply all the current and that you maybe had a power bus in addition.

You may want to edit your question with more system specs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have 14 switches, one side to ground, the other side to a resistor, then a LED, then 12V. So when you push a switch, the corresponding LED lights up.

Now you want to add a buzzer that buzzes when ANY switch is pressed?

Just connect 14 diodes, each diode connects to a switch and (all together) to the buzzer, other buzzer wire goes to 12V.